# Howto: convert boost::endian buffer types back into native format

Tags: c++, boost

The boost::endian examples for buffers.hpp show how to convert native format into big or little endian. How do I perform the inverse function to get the big/little endian format back into native format?

Example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <boost/endian/buffers.hpp>

using namespace boost::endian;

int main() {
uint64_t v= uint64_t(0x1011121314151617);

big_uint64_buf_t    b;
little_uint64_buf_t l;

// Set values, implicit native_to_*
b= v;
l= v;

// Get values, does not work
v= b;
v= l;

return 0;
}
```

The gcc compiler complains with:

example.cpp:17:6: error: cannot convert ‘boost::endian::big_uint64_buf_t {aka boost::endian::endian_buffer<(boost::endian::order)0, long unsigned int, 64ul>}’ to ‘uint64_t {aka long unsigned int}’ in assignment

```
 v= b;
  ^
```

A similar error occurs converting back from little endian format.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
v= b.value(); // and/or
v= l.value();
```

Although the value function usage is missing from examples, it is documented in the member function list.